# Are relative urls targeting same directory and subdirectory files to be started with a dot and a slash or not?

Tags: html, url, xhtml

There is an `index.xhtml` file and a `chapters` subdirectory in a directory which we can take as root. There are `chapter01.xhtml`, `chapter02.xhtml` etc. files in the `chapters` directory. How should I address `chapter01.xhtml` in `index.xhtml` code?

```
./chapters/chapter01.xhtml
```

or

```
chapters/chapter01.xhtml
```

?

And what if the chapters would be in the same directory - then

```
./chapter01.xhtml
```

or just

```
chapter01.xhtml
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are equivalent, but most people use the latter by convention. Plus, it's two keystrokes fewer.

Comment: As far as I can remember one of these doesn't work in some browsers.